# Jest: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, jasmine

When I run my jasmine test with Jest I get an error:

```
G:\git\diamant\SpaUI\node_modules\linqts\dist\src\index.js:10
    export { default as List } from './list';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

    > 1 | import { List } from 'linqts';
        | ^
      2 | import { ReportMessageData } from './../models/report.model';
      3 | import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
      4 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/feature-modules/report/services/report-message-flatten.service.ts:1:1)
```

I understand that I have to tell Jest to transform the code to plain Javascript, but I don't know how to do it.
My `jest.config.js` looks as follows:

```
var preset = require("jest-preset-angular/jest-preset");
module.exports = {
    ...preset,
    preset: "jest-preset-angular",
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!linqts)"],
    testMatch: ["**/*.test.ts"],
    globals: {
        ...preset.globals,
        "ts-jest": {
            ...preset.globals["ts-jest"],
            tsConfig: "src/tsconfig.test.json",
            isolatedModules: true
        }
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@diamant/feature-modules(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/feature-modules/$1',
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any solution available for this issue, i have the similar problem @Philip

Answer (score 3):

Jest doesn't support `ES6` module and hence throwing this error when you directly run the test with Jest. if you want to run like that then you have to add babel.

> In newer version of jest  babel-jest is now automatically loaded by Jest and fully integrated

Hope this answer your question.

**Adding babel in jest.**

**Installation** 
`babel-jest` is now automatically loaded by Jest and fully integrated. This step is only required if you are using babel-jest to transform TypeScript files.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

**Usage**

In your package.json file make the following changes:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

**Create .babelrc configuration file**
Create a `babel.config.json` config in your project root and enable some `presets`.
To start, you can use the env preset, which enables transforms for ES2015+

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

In order to enable the preset you have to define it in your `babel.config.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Check for more details on [Babel official site](https://babeljs.io/en/setup?fireglass_rsn=true#installation)

Comment: When I do that I get even more errors about unexpected tokens that were not problematic before